# How to access worksheets in EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm using the 3.1 release of EPPlus library to try to access a worksheet in an Excel file.  When I try either of the following methods I get a `System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added`.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(sourceFilePath)))
{
   var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

   // OR

   foreach (var excelWorksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
   ...
}
```

Exception Stack:

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelNamedRangeCollection.Add(String Name, ExcelRangeBase Range)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.GetDefinedNames()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.get_Workbook()
```

This seems like very basic functionality to have be so broken.. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the excel file was a `xls` file originally? EPPlus does only understand `xlsx`. Try to save it as `xlsx` manually first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workbook in question had named ranges defined.  These were causing problems so I created a new xlsx file with just the data I needed and it was able to open fine.

Comment: I know this is 2 years old, but if this solved your problem, you should accept your own answer to help highlight it for others who may have the same issue

Comment: this was the only probable solution for me, among all answers. I deleted Named Ranges; it didn't help. Point is that Worksheets object by itself throws the exception.

Answer (score 34):

I believe that excel does worksheets from index 1 not index 0

```
 var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

should be

```
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
```

to read the first worksheet.

Comment: In excel and pretty everything that connects to it, indexes start with 1, not 0. Nice reminder. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Also, you can manage them by referencing the name:

```
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
```

Answer (score 8):

At least with Epplus 3.1.3.0 you can simply use the following to access the first worksheet.

```
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the document created or saved with MS Excel (not OpenOffice, Libre Office, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To access/find all worksheets, I used:

```
 var file = new FileInfo(filename);

 ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(file);
           
 foreach (var excelWorksheet in pck.Workbook.Worksheets) 
 {
     Console.WriteLine("found sheet: " + excelWorksheet.Name);
 }
```