# EPPlus not loading cells correctly

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I have an excel with 3 worksheets. Every worksheet has around 100 columns.

There are some values that exist in the excel, but when I try to access them with EPPlus it returns no text.

What could be the problem?

To load the excel I do this:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(validarExcelDto.ExcelBase64);
using MemoryStream memoryStream = new(bytes);
using ExcelPackage package = new(memoryStream);
ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;
```

For example, in cell CG3 of the third sheet the text is "Hello". When I try to load it with EPPlus with this line `workbook.Worksheets[2].Cells["CG3"]` the text is "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the file itself. It was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus is the case of worksheets, numbering them starting from 1. So the third worksheet has index 3, not 2.

[How to access worksheets in EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568411/how-to-access-worksheets-in-epplus)

Documentation link: https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.0/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.html

I hope it helps

Comment: In the documentation says "The position of the worksheet. Collection is zero-based or one-base depending on the Package.Compatibility.IsWorksheets1Based propery. Default is Zero based". Mine is zero based. I can access the cell "CI3" for example.

Comment: @Carrivas If you try to access the cells using `[int Row, int Col]` does it return value?

Comment: It gets the same result that if I access with the adress.

Comment: @Carrivas have you checked in debbuger if there's anything in that cell? Maybe there's no Text, cause cell has different type?

Comment: In the debugger that cell has no text and no formula, but the type is the same that the other cell that has text and formula.